# What is the most succinct way to test if either of two variables are set?

Tags: php

What I'm doing is, if I haven't got an ID in either `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` then redirecting. Preference is given to `$_POST`. So I have this:

```
$bool = 0;
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $bool = 1;
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $bool = 1;
}
if (!$bool) {
    ...//redirect
}
```

Is there a quicker way to write this, APART from just removing the braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do:

```
$has_id = isset($_POST['id']) || isset($_SESSION['id']);

if (!$has_id) {
    // redirect
}
```

(I'd recommend you to give your variables more descriptive names than just `$bool`.)

Although if you aren't using the variable for anything else, you could just do:

```
if (!isset($_POST['id']) && !isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // redirect
}
```

Comment: what for? The name `$bool` suggests a thing or two about the nature of the variable.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I guess you are right. I was trying to write something that was exactly equivalent to what the OP had.

Comment: Would make perfect sense, if there was no prose in his post.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!( isset($_POST['id']) || isset($_SESSION['id']) ))
    redirect();
```

(not sure if I understand how what's given to `$_POST` is *preference*).

Comment: It evaluates to true, like the original code, what is it supposed to do? Let me quote "What I'm doing is, if I haven't got an ID in either $_POST or $_SESSION then...". What's supposed to happen?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Aaaah... I was tricked by the parentheses. I thought it read `if(    !(isset($_POST['id'])) || isset($_SESSION['id']) )`

Comment: I inserted a couple of spaces for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) || isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  $bool = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, simples

`$bool = (isset($_POST['id']) || isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? 1 : 0; // if isset, 1`
`($bool == 1?header(Location: www.whatever.com):null;`

Answer (score 0):

Using Conditional Operator, you can achieve this in one line statement

### Example:

```
c = (a == b) ? d : e;
```